# How To Hide Input Fields Based On Enum Radio Button Selection .NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, model-view-controller, enums

I have developed a page in C# using the MVC Razor technique,My code is following

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="" class="control-label">
                    IDMS Reference <font color="red">*</font></label><br />
                 <div class="radio col-md-4">
                     @Html.EnumRadioButtonFor(m => m.enumIDMSReference, false).DisableIf(() => 
                                                                          Model.IdmsRef == 2)

                </div>
```

```
 <div  class="col-md-4">
                <label for="" class="control-label">
                    IDMS Reference Number <font color="red">*</font></label><br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IdmsRefNo, new { @class = "form-control"  
                                            }).DisableIf(() => Model.InwardBranch == true)
</div>
```

And my Enum class is following,

```
public enum enumIDMSReference
{
    [Description("Applicable")]
    Applicable = 1,

    [Description("Not Applicable")]
    NotApplicable = 2,

}
```

Here if we click the Not Applicable radio button, then the IDMS Reference Number input field should be disable and the input IdmsRefNo field should enable only for the applicable radio button so how to do it in JQuery or any other solution?.
Please anybody help

Comment: Can you give a sample code please?

Comment: Check this link http://romikoderbynew.com/2012/02/23/asp-net-mvc-rendering-enum-dropdownlists-radio-buttons-and-listboxes/

Comment: I can't find the solution in that link. Please if you can help then help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you want to disable a field based on the selected radio option. You can bind the change event of your radio buttons and disable/enable your textbox accordingly.  [[.NET FIDDLE]](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7vxZnA)

```
$('input[name="enumIDMSReference"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'NotApplicable') {
        $('#IdmsRefNo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#IdmsRefNo').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

You can iterate across your enum values like so (I'm not checking for nulls, which you can do on your own):

```
@foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(Model.enumIDMSReference.GetType()))
{
    var memInfo = Model.enumIDMSReference.GetType().GetMember(value.ToString());
    var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    var description = ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;

     @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.enumIDMSReference, value);
     @Html.Label(description);
     @Html.Raw("<br />");
}
```

You can expand this further by disabling/enabling the textbox by default server-side depending on the value of enumIDMSReference.